# Fragment has target not in fragment Manager after rotation of screen with retained async task fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have been following this tutorial by Alex Lockwood (2013) on how to make a thread report back to a new activity instance after a configuration change.

http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html

All was working great until I tried to do this within a nested fragment. basically Activity adds Fragment A and Fragment A gets replaced with Fragment B and inside fragment B starts the a async task thread.

However, if I go back to Fragment A (via backstack) and then try to rotate I get the following exception stated in the title.

Here is the code

**Main Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if(savedInstanceState == null)
        {
             FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
             ft.add(android.R.id.content, new FragmentA()).commit();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**Fragment A**

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment implements OnClickListener
{

    private Button GoToFragmentB;
    private ViewGroup container;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,  Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);
    this.container = container;
    GoToFragmentB = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.bGoToFragmentB);
    GoToFragmentB.setOnClickListener(this);
    return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentB fb = new FragmentB();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(container.getId(), fb, FragmentB.class.getName());
        fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

}
```

**Fragment B**

```
public class FragmentB extends Fragment implements OnClickListener, ThreadFragment.AsyncTaskCallbacks{

    private ThreadFragment mThreadFragment;
    private ProgressBar progress_horizontal;
    private TextView percent_progress;
    private Button task_button;

    private static final String KEY_CURRENT_PROGRESS = "current_progress"; 
    private static final String KEY_PERCENT_PROGRESS = "percent_progress"; 


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,  Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_b, container, false);

        progress_horizontal = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progress_horizontal);
        percent_progress = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.percent_progress);
        task_button = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.task_button);
        task_button.setOnClickListener(this);



        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        if(savedInstanceState != null)
        {
            progress_horizontal.setProgress(savedInstanceState.getInt(KEY_CURRENT_PROGRESS)); 
            percent_progress.setText(savedInstanceState.getString(KEY_PERCENT_PROGRESS)); 

        }

        FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        mThreadFragment = (ThreadFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag(ThreadFragment.class.getName());

        if(mThreadFragment == null)
        {
            mThreadFragment = new ThreadFragment();
            mThreadFragment.setTargetFragment(this, 0);
            fm.beginTransaction().add(mThreadFragment, ThreadFragment.class.getName()).commit();
        }

        if(mThreadFragment.isRunning() == true)
        {
            task_button.setText(getString(R.string.cancel));
        }
        else
        {
            task_button.setText(getString(R.string.start));
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt(KEY_CURRENT_PROGRESS, progress_horizontal.getProgress()); 
        outState.putString(KEY_PERCENT_PROGRESS, percent_progress.getText().toString()); 

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(mThreadFragment.isRunning() == true)
        {
            mThreadFragment.cancel();
        }
        else
        {
            mThreadFragment.start();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onPreExecute() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        task_button.setText(getString(R.string.cancel));
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.task_started_msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    @Override
    public void onProgressUpdate(int percent)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        progress_horizontal.setProgress(percent * progress_horizontal.getMax() / 100);
        percent_progress.setText(percent + "%");
    }


    @Override
    public void onCancelled() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        task_button.setText("Start");
        progress_horizontal.setProgress(0);
        percent_progress.setText("0%");

    }


    @Override
    public void onPostExecute() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        task_button.setText(getString(R.string.start));
        progress_horizontal.setProgress(progress_horizontal.getMax());
        percent_progress.setText(getString(R.string.one_hundred_percent));
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.task_complete_msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mThreadFragment.pause();
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mThreadFragment.resume();
        super.onResume();
    }

}
```

**Thread Fragment**

```
public class ThreadFragment extends Fragment {


    static interface AsyncTaskCallbacks
    {
        void onPreExecute();
        void onProgressUpdate(int percent);
        void onCancelled();
        void onPostExecute();
    }

    private AsyncTaskCallbacks mCallback;
    private boolean mRunning;
    private boolean isPause;

    private TestTask mTask;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onAttach(activity);
        if(!(getTargetFragment() instanceof AsyncTaskCallbacks))
        {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Target fragment must implement the AsyncTaskCallbacks interface.");
        }


        if(getTargetFragment() != null)
        {
        mCallback = (AsyncTaskCallbacks) getTargetFragment();
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
        cancel();

    }

    public void start()
    {
        if(mRunning == false)
        {
            mTask = new TestTask();
            mTask.execute();
            mRunning = true;
        }
    }

    public void cancel()
    {
        if(mRunning == true)
        {
            mTask.cancel(false);
            mTask = null;
            mRunning = false;
            isPause = false;
        }
    }

    public void pause()
    {
        if(mRunning == true)
        {
            isPause = true;
        }
    }

    public void resume()
    {
        isPause = false;
    }

    public boolean isRunning()
    {
        return mRunning;
    }

    private class TestTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void>
    {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mCallback.onPreExecute();
            mRunning = true;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) 
        {


                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                for(int i = 0; !isCancelled() && i < 100; i++)
                {
                    if(isPause == true)
                    {
                        sleep();
                    }

                    SystemClock.sleep(100);
                    publishProgress(i);
                }



            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mCallback.onProgressUpdate(values[0]);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mCallback.onCancelled();
            mRunning = false;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mCallback.onPostExecute();
            mRunning = false;
        }

        private void sleep()
        {
            try
            {
                while(isPause)
                {
                Thread.sleep(500);
                }
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


    }



}
```

My LogCat

```
09-06 19:49:31.068: E/AndroidRuntime(2402): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-06 19:49:31.068: E/AndroidRuntime(2402): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failure saving state: ThreadFragment{40ce2700 #2 com.ersen.asynctaskpausetest.ThreadFragment} has target not in fragment manager: FragmentB{40d3a170}
09-06 19:49:31.068: E/AndroidRuntime(2402):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveAllState(FragmentManager.java:1699)
09-06 19:49:31.068: E/AndroidRuntime(2402):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onSaveInstanceState(FragmentActivity.java:547)
09-06 19:49:31.068: E/AndroidRuntime(2402):     at android.app.Activity.performSaveInstanceState(Activity.java:1147)
09-06 19:49:31.068: E/AndroidRuntime(2402):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnSaveInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1216)
09-06 19:49:31.068: E/AndroidRuntime(2402):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3666)
09-06 19:49:31.068: E/AndroidRuntime(2402):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:141)
09-06 19:49:31.068: E/AndroidRuntime(2402):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1240)
09-06 19:49:31.068: E/AndroidRuntime(2402):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-06 19:49:31.068: E/AndroidRuntime(2402):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-06 19:49:31.068: E/AndroidRuntime(2402):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
09-06 19:49:31.068: E/AndroidRuntime(2402):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-06 19:49:31.068: E/AndroidRuntime(2402):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-06 19:49:31.068: E/AndroidRuntime(2402):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
09-06 19:49:31.068: E/AndroidRuntime(2402):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
09-06 19:49:31.068: E/AndroidRuntime(2402):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**------------EDIT UPDATE 08 SEPT 2014--------------------**

I added this to my fragment B on destroy method

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    mThreadFragment.setTargetFragment(null , -1);

}
```

I made the following adjustment to my Fragment B onActivityCreated. Please note the else is invoked if the fragment has been found by fragmentManger.findFragmentByTag

```
if(mThreadFragment == null)
    {
        mThreadFragment = new ThreadFragment();
        mThreadFragment.setTargetFragment(this, 0);
        fm.beginTransaction().add(mThreadFragment, ThreadFragment.class.getName()).commit();
    }
    else
    {
        mThreadFragment.setTargetFragment(this, 0);
    }
```

I made the following change to OnAttach inside the thread fragment

```
if(getTargetFragment() != null)
{

    if((getTargetFragment().isVisible()) || getTargetFragment().isAdded())
    {
           mCallback = (AsyncTaskCallbacks) getTargetFragment();

    }
    else
    {
        mCallback = null;
    }
}
```

The difference now is I am no longer getting the error I mentioned above. I can start a task. Destory fragment b and rotate (configuration change) without any issue. However, if I go back into fragment b (make a new instance since its destroyed) and then start a new task. I am getting this new error which is saying that fragment b is not attached.

```
09-08 14:07:28.495: E/AndroidRuntime(1650): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment FragmentB{40cea860} not attached to Activity
09-08 14:07:28.495: E/AndroidRuntime(1650):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.getResources(Fragment.java:603)
09-08 14:07:28.495: E/AndroidRuntime(1650):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.getString(Fragment.java:625)
09-08 14:07:28.495: E/AndroidRuntime(1650):     at com.ersen.asynctaskpausetest.FragmentB.onPreExecute(FragmentB.java:119)
09-08 14:07:28.495: E/AndroidRuntime(1650):     at com.ersen.asynctaskpausetest.ThreadFragment$TestTask.onPreExecute(ThreadFragment.java:114)
```

Its saying that fragment b is not attached to activity. These are the culprit lines in question.

```
@Override
public void onPreExecute() 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    task_button.setText(getString(R.string.cancel));
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.task_started_msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

since accessing string resource needs an activity but its weird because if I make new fragment B shouldn't it be attached to activity already?

**FINAL UPDATE: FIXED VERSION: Using the Activity to handle the callbacks as opposed to fragment B**

Below is the code that was changed.

**ThreadFragment:  OnAttach**

```
@Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onAttach(activity);
        if(!(activity instanceof AsyncTaskCallbacks))
        {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Target fragment must implement the AsyncTaskCallbacks interface.");
        }



        mCallback = (AsyncTaskCallbacks) activity;

    }
```

I removed the getTargetFragment and used activity reference

**Fragment B**

No longer implements the ThreadFragment.AsyncTaskCallbacks interface
Removed all the code related to setTargetFragment.
The methods implemented by ThreadFragment.AsyncTaskCallbacks was kept but no longer overridden just so activity can call these to do the usual stuff.

```
public void onPreExecute() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        task_button.setText(getString(R.string.cancel));
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.task_started_msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }



    public void onProgressUpdate(int percent)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        progress_horizontal.setProgress(percent * progress_horizontal.getMax() / 100);
        percent_progress.setText(percent + "%");
    }



    public void onCancelled() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        task_button.setText("Start");
        progress_horizontal.setProgress(0);
        percent_progress.setText("0%");

    }



    public void onPostExecute() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        task_button.setText(getString(R.string.start));
        progress_horizontal.setProgress(progress_horizontal.getMax());
        percent_progress.setText(getString(R.string.one_hundred_percent));
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.task_complete_msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

**Main Activity**

Implements ThreadFragment.AsyncTaskCallbacks
Added 3 instance variables FragmentB, FragmentManger, and a Boolean.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements ThreadFragment.AsyncTaskCallbacks{

FragmentB FB;
FragmentManager fragmentManager;
boolean didFragmentBStartATask;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    if(savedInstanceState == null)
    {
         FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
         ft.add(android.R.id.content, new FragmentA()).commit();
    }
    else
    {
        didFragmentBStartATask = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("didFragmentBStartATask");
        if(didFragmentBStartATask)
        {
            FB = (FragmentB)fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(FragmentB.class.getName());
        }

    }

}
```

On Create will initialise the fragment manager.
If its a restored instance get value of Boolean to check if fragment b did a task. 
if true, find fragment B by tag.

On save instance state just puts Boolean into bundle

```
@Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putBoolean("didFragmentBStartATask", didFragmentBStartATask);
    }
```

The implemented methods via the interface

```
@Override
    public void onPreExecute() 
    {
        didFragmentBStartATask = true;
        if(FB == null)
        {
            FB = (FragmentB)fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(FragmentB.class.getName());
        }

        FB.onPreExecute();

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressUpdate(int percent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        FB.onProgressUpdate(percent);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        FB.onCancelled();

    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        FB.onPostExecute();
        didFragmentBStartATask = false;

    }
```

On pre execute,, sets Boolean to true
We must check if FB is null to prevent null pointer . if its null, find the fragment (this need for first time launch)

After that just use the FB instance to call the methods in the to do the same stuff as before.

On post execute set Boolean to false because its done

Comment: You might be able to avoid this problem by having your retained worker fragment (the one that is responsible for creating and managing the `Thread`/`AsyncTask`) communicate directly with the activity instead of directly with the nested fragment that originally started it. Fragment-to-fragment communication is a tiny bit trickier because it becomes possible for one of the fragments to communicate with the other before the activity has actually added it to its view. I imagine that the backstack and use of nested fragments would only make this more delicate.

Comment: In other words, the nested fragment can send a notification to the activity when it wants the thread fragment to start/stop doing work, and then the activity does the actual work of holding a reference to the `Fragment` and communicating with it directly.

Comment: Theoretically using `setTargetFragment` should also work (I wrote an example which uses it in the [sample code](https://github.com/alexjlockwood/worker-fragments/tree/master/src/com/adp/retaintask/extra) accompanying my blog post too).

Comment: Thank you for this advice and thank you for making the tutorial. I will try out using the activity to implement the callbacks.

Comment: Yes I originally followed the code located in the extras directory as this was closely related to what I was doing.

Comment: @AlexLockwood Thanks, using the activity to handle the call backs did it no more problems that I can find :) Not sure how to mark your answer as correct but i will up vote. I will add the code now.

Comment: The code is added. Read from "FINAL UPDATE: FIXED VERSION: Using the Activity to handle the callbacks as opposed to fragment B"

Answer (score 3):

Kind of late to the party, but you should consider removing your calls to "setTargetFragment(this, 0)" for your "child" fragments. Instead, you should use getChildFragmentManager() instead of getFragmentManager() when you want to create a "child fragment" from your Fragment B.

Then in your "child fragment", you would use getParentFragment() instead of getTargetFragment() to find your enclosing fragment. The two parts of code will look something like:

```
threadFragment = new ThreadFragment();
FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();
fm.beginTransaction().add(threadFragment, ThreadFragment.class.getName()).commit();
```

Then in your ThreadFragment, you will no longer use getTargetFragment() to find your Fragment B. Instead you will call getParentFragment().

```
if(!(getParentFragment() instanceof AsyncTaskCallbacks))
    {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Target fragment must implement the AsyncTaskCallbacks interface.");
    }

    if(getParentFragment() != null)
    {
    mCallback = (AsyncTaskCallbacks) getParentFragment();
    }
```

And finally, in your Fragment B, you need to make some changes to find your ThreadFragment. You need to change it to use the ChildFragmentManager

```
FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();
mThreadFragment = (ThreadFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag(ThreadFragment.class.getName());
```

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation of [setTargetFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html)

> public void setTargetFragment (Fragment fragment, int requestCode) Optional target for this fragment. This may be used, for example, if this fragment is being started by another, and when done wants to give a result back to the first.

Try doing this.

put this in the fragment that causes the problems(in this case may be in your `Fragment A`):

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(final Bundle outState) {
setTargetFragment(null, -1);
        ...
}
```

and remember to set it to the real target fragment when you need it.

**Edit**

You may try doing this in your `Fragment B`

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(final Bundle outState) {
Fragment threadFrag = new ThreadFrag();
threadFrag.setTargetFragment(this , -1);
        ...
}
```

Comment: Please see the edited answer and lemme know if that solved your problem.

Comment: Hi, thank you, sorry for the delay. I implemented the solutions you have stated in addition to some code I added. Please see my edited answer above. Another problem has is occurring but its no longer the problem related to no target fragment blah blah